# Type signature that infers all values

Tags: typescript, types

This is in TypeScript 4.0.2. The type system can infer some of the values from the type signature in the example below. I'm perplexed though why it can't infer the concrete value of the last element in `const b`.

Can anyone explain why, and how I can write a type signature that can?

```
declare function identityA<T extends string[]>(p: readonly [...T]): T
declare function identityB<T extends any[]>(p: readonly [...T]): [...T]

const a = identityA(['r', 's'])  // ['r', 's']
const b = identityB([...a, 3])  // ['r', 's', number]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TypeScript's type inference uses a variety of heuristics to figure out when to widen [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html) and when to leave them as narrow as possible.  For example, when you write

```
let s = ""; // string
let n = 0; // number
let b = true; // boolean
```

the types of the *variables* `s`, `n`, and `b` are widened to `string`, `number`, and `boolean`, respectively... the assumption is that since `let` declarations allow you to reassign values, you probably want to do that.  On the other hand, when you write

```
const sC = ""; // ""
const nC = 0; // 0
const bC = true; // true
```

the types of the variables `sC`, `nC`, and `bC` are kept narrow as `""`, `0`, and `true`, respectively.  The assumption is that because you can't change those values, you have no reason to allow more than those single values in the types.

---

For type parameters, like the `T` in your `identityA()` and `identityB()` functions, the compiler does something else.  This is mentioned in [microsoft/TypeScript#10676](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676):

> During type argument inference for a call expression the type inferred for a type parameter `T` is widened to its widened literal type if (...) `T` has no constraint or its constraint does not include primitive or literal types

In

```
declare function identityA<T extends string[]>(p: readonly [...T]): T
```

the type parameter `T` has a [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) that includes the primitive `string` type, and thus `T` will not be widened from, say, `["r", "s"]` to `[string, string]`.  On the other hand, in

```
declare function identityB<T extends any[]>(p: readonly [...T]): [...T]
```

the type parameter `T`'s constraint does not include any literal or primitive types, so `T` will be widened from, say, `[3]` to `[number]`.  Or since the `"r"` and `"s"` types were already non-widened from a previous inference, `T` will be widened from `["r", "s", 3]` to `["r", "s", number]`.

It's confusing, right?  Never mind that by using the [variadic tuple type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094) `[...T]` in your `p` parameter type you are giving the compiler a hint that you want to infer [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) for `T` instead of just array types.

---

So that's why it happens.  What can you do to fix it?

If you have control over the call site, you can use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to explicitly ask the compiler to infer the narrowest possible type for what you're passing in.  This happens before `T` gets inferred:

```
const iBAsConst = identityB([...iA, 3] as const)  // ['r', 's', 3]
```

But you asked how to change the *signature* to turn `identityB()`'s type parameter into a literal-preferring inference thingy.  You can do this by changing the `any[]` to something that includes primitives.  For example:

```
type Narrowable = string | number | boolean | symbol | 
  object | undefined | void | null | {};
declare function identityC<T extends Narrowable[]>(p: readonly [...T]): [...T]
const iC = identityC(["r", "s", 3]); // ['r', 's', 3]
```

Just about anything can be assigned to `Narrowable`, like a weird `any` or `unknown` that also works as a keep-this-narrow hint.

Hooray, right?

---

If that all seems like evil magic to you, I agree.  A while ago I opened [microsoft/TypeScript#30680](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680) to request some syntax to *explicitly* ask for "`as const`"-like behavior for the signature side of a function.  Then you'd be able to write something like

```
// don't try this, it won't work:
declare function identityB<T extends any[] as const>(p: readonly [...T]): [...T];
```

to get the same effect.  Alas, it's just sitting there as a suggestion as of today (2020-09-24), so for now you have to continue to practice the dark arts to get the inference you're looking for.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAzhC8ECIEG4IHo3TAJwJYDsBzAWAChRJ84IAGVDCfAVwFsAjEbMiiN6nJiHqY2Ae1GgAhlTJkAxqPxRIUAMLUkwxAnmLljdfDrpMNXUshtDEAUJM3sg2aWfOAJiDnBJ2EBABmTPhyYLiKELge+KFgAJ4AggA8ACoQIAAeYCD4bjDKeEQA2gC6AHwAFAAOAFwQvpJuisCxEIUAdB3JxQCUtclkHl4+foHBoeGR2TGxAEIpaZnZuRDSsSUVNXUgDU0t7Z09tfttXc4KFhHx1JPRuHHx5YUA5NhPADQQT1BPPRD2z68Pl8fuZ9LgZtcotMZo8Om1cPEPgBmX7-F7vT7fD7MdicYpnPSQcHxNSEyFTO6zWEdBHI4orGDnZTdP4MAEY4F01ykOKVPwAOR82FEAHdJGxQNR8gRCBAAD6MVgcbDy3jiKRUBVQWLsCSq0RsABWnkgCqCHn8BBAblVADdRJFVcxgMBVQBvAC+yAGnm8vgCQRCYSoN2mqnmGSyORgguwwrFEpA6yqtXqjXwzVacK6vSzB1BROsocpqkeCGwCA+CCglYgKO6WnZQKxdfpzgY6aekBwLTAAAtcFAPncICLFF3R6JsABrapkDu+4YBsbBiJQylzVKRpYwVYlBkQJlgDap7bpzPHHNHbPFZBAA)

Comment: Amazing answer, sir!

Answer (score 1):

If you mark the argument to `identityB` `as const`, TS can narrow the type of the items in the tuple argument to their literal types. Otherwise, it just uses the `typeof` the last parameter.

```
declare function identityA<T extends string[]>(p: readonly [...T]): T
declare function identityB<T extends any[]>(p: readonly [...T]): [...T]

const a = identityA(['r', 's'])  // ['r', 's']
const b = identityB([...a, 3] as const)  // ['r', 's', 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

As of TypeScript 5.0.0 (issue [#30680](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680), PR [#51865](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/51865)), you can use the `const T` modifier on the generic type, which causes it to take the most precise type possible:

```js
declare function identity<const T>(p: T): T;
```

```js
const a = identity(['r', 's'])  // readonly ['r', 's']
const b = identity([...a, 3])   // readonly ['r', 's', 3]
```

(This is similar to using an [`as const`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66993264/what-does-the-as-const-mean-in-typescript-and-what-is-its-use-case) assertion on each call site, but you only need to do it once in the declaration.)

### Removing `readonly`

The example in your question also strips the [`readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types) modifier from the returned type. To adjust our new `identity` function so that it strips `readonly`, we can use [`-readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers):

```js
declare function identity<const T>(p: T): { -readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P] };
```

Note that despite the object mapping syntax (`{ ... }`), this `identity` function still works for arrays and [even primitive types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78202581/525872).

```js
const a = identity(['r', 's'])  // ['r', 's']
const b = identity([...a, 3])   // ['r', 's', 3]
```

To further remove `readonly` from nested objects, as in `identity({ foo: { bar: 0 }})`, I recommend using the [`DeepWritable<T>`](https://github.com/ts-essentials/ts-essentials/tree/master/lib/deep-writable) type from the [ts-essentials](https://github.com/ts-essentials/ts-essentials) package:

```js
import type { DeepWritable } from "ts-essentials";

declare function identity<const T>(p: T): DeepWritable<T>;
```

P.S. Thanks to [@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) for laying all of the groundwork to make `const T` happen: They wrote up the GitHub issue I linked, and provided the earlier extensive answer for pre-5.0.0 TypeScript.